# HTTP сервер для работы с программой на qt

Tags: c++, qt, http

Итак, примерно моя задача такова:

HTTP сервер создает соединение по какому-нибудь адресу, например `localhost:4567`, по которому доступен выбранный пользователем каталог.

Например: В каталоге `test/` лежат файлы `index.html`, `contact.html`, `menu.html`. Я создаю соединение и по адресу `localhost:4567/index.html` у меня открывается страница из каталога `test/`, если зайти на `localhost:4567/menu.html` открывается `menu.html` из каталога `test/` и так далее. При этом я хочу из своего основного **Qt** приложения периодически обновлять страницу (т.е. не в браузере нажимать F5, а чтобы моя программа/сервер обновляла страницу сама).

**Если вкратце**, у сервера мне нужно всего 2 функции: сделать доступным для браузера содержимое какого-либо каталога по адресу `localhost:4567` и чтобы была возможность обновлять страницу из своей программы на **Qt**.

Нужно писать свой HTTP сервер или есть готовые решения? В какую сторону копать, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/nitroshare/qhttpengine

Вот эта библиотека умеет делать, то описано в первой части. Указываем каталог и через веб-сервер есть доступ к этим файлам.

По поводу обновления из qt приложения, я вижу такую схему: веб-страница с определенным интервалом через ajax отправляет запрос к API, который тоже можно реализовать средствами вышеуказанной библиотеки, а сервер отвечает: нужно обновить страницу или нет.

Comment: хм, я несколько далек от ajax, для этого нужен Node.js?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Берете обычный Апач и настраиваете его как вам хочется.

Ключевые моменты - это индексация каталога и виртуальные хосты. На виртуальных хостах можно сделать чтобы по каждому отдельному порту открывалось содержимое конкретной папки.

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, но мое приложение будет запускаться не только на моем компьютере, где я могу настроить апач, но и на компьютерах где он вообще не установлен.